# Iterating through IHtmlElementCollection

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a VB webapplication that needs to read information from an excisting webpage on the internet. Therefore I use the mshtml library. I read the html into an ihtmldocument3 interface. After that I iterate through an ihtmlelementcollection and everything worked fine in Visual Studio 2010 Debugger. At least, the first time. When I debug the code for the second time, after iterating a few elements, the next elements return nothing and I get an exception. (When I break into the code the ihtmlelementcollection shows 0 items.) When I rename all the variables, it runs properly, but again, only the first time.

Here's the code I use to debug. I have outlined the actual code because that responds into an exception (null reference). Do I need to manually release a collection or something or am I doing something stupid?

```
'global variable
Private tables as IHTMLElementCollection
...........................................
        Dim tableChildren As IHTMLElementCollection = tables(3).children
        Dim trElements As IHTMLElementCollection = tableChildren.item(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")

        Dim intCount As Integer 'just for debugging purposes
        For Each element As IHTMLElement In trElements
            intCount += 1 'for debugging purposes
            Debug.Print(intCount.ToString & vbNewLine & element.innerHTML)
            'strLine1 = element.children(0).innerText
            'strLine2 = element.children(1).innerText
            'and so on...
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by this point you've already resolved the problem one way or another, but I thought I'd suggest the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).  It has the advantage of being written to support just this type of scenario, and (as far as I know) is a native .NET library rather than being COM-based. It might be a better fit for your situation.